# How to change the position of the block in magento2.2.2

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.2, cms-block

**I just installed a buy-now plugin**, But it affects the display of other features.[image]

How should I change it so that the **buynow-button** is displayed on top of product-addto-links.
Please help me!!!!

**I don't know much about magento.**

> app/code/Prince/Buynow/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="Prince_Buynow::css/buynow.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View"
               name="product.buynow"
               template="Prince_Buynow::buynow-view.phtml"
               before="-" ifconfig="buynow/general/enable_view"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View"
               name="product.buynow.config"
               template="Prince_Buynow::buynow-view.phtml"
               before="-" ifconfig="buynow/general/enable_view"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="related.product.addto">
        <block class="Prince\Buynow\Block\Product\ListProduct"
               ifconfig="buynow/general/enable_related"
               name="product.buynow.related"
               before="-" template="Prince_Buynow::buynow-list.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not just use the "instant purchase" feature?

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong. I am using version 2.2.2.And i enabled the "instant purchase" feature,but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: How you added this button ?, I think It will happen in your product page by moving the `<div>`

Comment: @PRINCE I installed this plugin [link](https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-buynow)

Comment: i think for instant purchase button to appear you need to be logged in and possibly you might need to have a stored payment method, although i dont quite remember

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.buynow" destination="product.info.form.content" before="product.info.addtocart"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

<sup>D'ont forget to clean the cache.</sup>

Comment: I tried your method,But it doesn't seem to take effect,I cleared the cache.[link](https://prnt.sc/lf9t0l)

Comment: Try to enable the path hints, then give me the block names of the two blocks `add to cart` and `by now` https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-enable-template-path-hints-magento-2.html

Comment: Thank you very much,PRINCE.I have found the reason for this problem,and i have solved this problem.

Comment: Cool, You can accept the answer if it helped you